# didSelectRowAt no funciona

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, textfield

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el que tengo que cargar con información un textField. Para ello, he creado tablas y le he dado eventos al row, de tal manera que al hacerle click muestre los detalles en el textField de otro ViewController. El problema es que al darla click la primera vez no se carga, al darle click(por segunda vez) a otro row se carga la información del primer row y así sucesivamente.

```
    class ViewControllerGestionGaleria : UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
        
        var modelo : Model?
        var detalleFigura : Figura?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let numeroMaterial = indexPath.section
        let material = modelo?.material[numeroMaterial]
        
        let figura = material?.figuras?[indexPath.row]
        
            let celda  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: modelo!.ROW_CELL) as! RowCell

            if let texto = figura?.identificador {
                celda.nombreFigura.text = texto
            }
            
            if let foto = figura?.foto{
                celda.fotoFigura.image = foto
            }


        
        return celda
    }
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let modelo = modelo?.material[indexPath.section]
        let figura = modelo?.figuras?[indexPath.row]
        
        detalleFigura = figura
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if segue.identifier != nil {
           switch segue.identifier! {

           case "segue":
               
               let destModifcarFgura = segue.destination as! ViewControllerDetallesFigura
               destModifcarFgura.figuraDetalle = detalleFigura
               destModifcarFgura.modelo = modelo
               
               break
           default:
               break
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: En dónde tienes el `@IBOutlet` que conectas al `tableView` con el controlador?

Comment: En el código está, pero se me olvido copiarlo en la pregunta.  El programa compila y se ejecuta a la perfección, lo único que pasa es que el didSelectAtRow lo hace con retraso